# Ссылка внутри проекта xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

Как поставить путь внутри проекта xcode?
Внутри проекта есть папка `ProjectFolder/WebShell/Sites/Folder/index.html`
Как к нему путь поставить?

```
self.url = "file://........"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При компиляции проект упаковывается в bundle, поэтому нужно ссылаться внутри пакета.

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "folder/index", withExtension: "html")